# Mongodb - Aggregation and Sum for each object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to aggregate for each "Product" object from the sales database, and sum "Price" and "Quantity" to make a product classification.

I was able to group by "Products" but I can't sum Price and Quantity to the each object.

```
{$group: {
     _id: '$products.items',
     totalprice:{$sum: "$products.items.price"},
}}
```

Below sample of sales database, where I need to return the sum of the "Price" and "Quantity" fields sold for each "Products".

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d753707c0cd851e80da914c"
    },
    "created_on": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1567962886000"
        }
    },
    "custumer": {
        "name": "Teste",
        "cep": "teste",
        "address": "teste",
        "district": "test",
        "city": "test",
        "numb": "50",
        "comple": "test",
        "state": "test",
        "cpf": "test",
        "birth": "30/09/1977",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "phone": {
            "$numberDouble": "1111111111111"
        },
        "gender": "M",
        "portalt": {
            "status": "true",
            "vendor": "test",
            "phone": {
                "$numberDouble": "11111111111"
            },
            "sim": "011111111111",
            "salesnumb": "1222222222222222222"
        }
    },
    "payment": {
        "method": "Boleto",
        "type": "Parcelado",
        "installments": "5",
        "billing_date": "15"
    },
    **"products": {
        "items": {
            "5d515979736802000415a561": {
                "item": {
                    "_id": "5d515979736802000415a561",
                    "name_produto": "Product 1",
                    "resumo": "Minutos ilimitados,20GB + 2GB",
                    "price": "110",
                    "_image": "images/test.jpg"
                },
                "quantity": {
                    "$numberInt": "2"
                },
                "price": {
                    "$numberInt": "220"
                }
            },
            "5d515aba736802000415a562": {
                "item": {
                    "_id": "5d515aba736802000415a562",
                    "name_produto": "Product 2",
                    "resumo": "Minutos ilimitados,3GB + 1GB",
                    "price": "80",
                    "_image": "images/test.jpg"
                },
                "quantity": {
                    "$numberInt": "1"
                },
                "price": {
                    "$numberInt": "80"
                }
            },
            "5d515dbf736802000415a564": {
                "item": {
                    "_id": "5d515dbf736802000415a564",
                    "name_produto": "Product 3",
                    "resumo": "Minutos ilimitados,30GB + 3GB",
                    "price": "150",
                    "_image": "images/test.jpg"
                },
                "quantity": {
                    "$numberInt": "1"
                },
                "price": {
                    "$numberInt": "150"
                }
            }
        },**
        "totalItems": {
            "$numberInt": "4"
        },
        "totalPrice": {
            "$numberInt": "450"
        }
    },
    "seller": {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5cd086787dc59921bcad94d8"
        },
        "name": "test"
    }
}
```

I need output something like:

```
_id:Object
    5d515979736802000415a561:{sum_price: 300, sum_quantity: 30 }
    5d515aba736802000415a562:{sum_price: 500, sum_quantity: 60 }
    5d515dbf736802000415a564:{sum_price: 600, sum_quantity: 70 }
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: why is that items in products not an array ? Also you're looking into summing price in item or the other price below quantity ?

Comment: Do you have any control over the data design?   IDs as keys and then again as `_id` inside an array are a tad suspect...

Comment: Thanks a lot srinivasy and Buzz Moschetti , I also think it should be inside an array, but it was designed this way in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's go with the OP ask to sum the individual product price and quantity.  Stripping away the other fields which are not relevant to the ask, we arrive at something like this:

```
var r =
[
 {
     _id:0,
     "products": {
        "items": {
            "5d515979736802000415a561": {
                "quantity": 2,
                "price": 220,
            },
            "5d515aba736802000415a562": {
                "quantity": 1,
                "price": 80
            }
        }
     }
 }
 , {
     _id:1,
     "products": {
        "items": {
            "5d515979736802000415a561": {  // deliberately same id as doc above but different quantity and price
                "quantity": 3,
                "price": 330
            },
            "5d515aba736802000415a562": { // same
                "quantity": 2,
                "price": 160
            },
            "5d515979736802000415ZZZZ": {  // different than above; adds "third item"
                "quantity": 4,
                "price": 200
            }
        }
     }
 }
 ];
```

Note that the whole inner `item` field is basically not important, not the least of which it only contains the unit price, not the total price (amount) and quantity per product.

```
            "5d515dbf736802000415a564": {
                "item": {
                    "_id": "5d515dbf736802000415a564",
                    // etc
```

So now we employ the `$objectToArray` to turn the keys into rvals.  That gives us something we can `$group` on, and so here is a solution:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {X: {$objectToArray: "$products.items"}}}
,{$unwind: "$X"}
,{$group: {_id: "$X.k", tot_q: {$sum:"$X.v.quantity"}, tot_amt: {$sum:"$X.v.price"}} }
                      ]);
```

which given the input above yields:

```
{ "_id" : "5d515979736802000415ZZZZ", "tot_q" : 4, "tot_amt" : 200 }
{ "_id" : "5d515aba736802000415a562", "tot_q" : 3, "tot_amt" : 240 }
{ "_id" : "5d515979736802000415a561", "tot_q" : 5, "tot_amt" : 550 }
```